# Validar largo de un input

Tags: javascript, html, validación, input

Necesito validar el largo de un `input` y usé parte del código que está aquí por eso lo pregunto acá.

```
<input type="text" name="rut" required oninput="checkRut(this)" placeholder="Rut">
<input type="text" name="nombre" required oninput="checklargo(this)" placeholder="Nombre">
```

Este es el `html` y su `input` que es un formulario igual.

Lo que viene a continuación es la función:

```
function checklargo(nombre) {
var palabra=nombre.value;   
    alert(palabra);

if(palabra.length > 5) {nombre.setCustomValidity("Excede el largo permitido"); return false;}

}
```

Le puse el `alert` para saber que iba conteniendo a cada minuto la variable y como funcionaría el `if`.

Cuando cargo la primera vez el formulario funciona, luego de marcar el primer error correctamente no deja de marcar error aunque esté correcto.

Y el `validarut` de este hilo funciona perfecto y no sé porque el mío no, si es la misma idea.

Saludos y gracias.

Comment: Ayudaría que agregues el mensaje de error

Comment: Alguna de las respuesta te ayudó?. Si es así, márcala como respuesta, si no, déjanos un comentario para saber como te podemos seguir ayudando. [Haz el tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que conozcas como funciona la comunidad.

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que al haber error estableces un mensaje, pero no lo quitas cuando el valor es correcto y por eso es que el campo sigue marcado con error.

Solución: Crea una variable para el mensaje de validación (vacía) / error (texto) y actualiza de acuerdo al valor:

```js
function checklargo(campo, max) {
    var palabra=campo.value;
    // Crear mensaje, en blanco para valor correcto
    var msg = '';
    if(palabra.length > max) {
        // Hay error, actualizar mensaje
        msg = "Excede el largo permitido";
    }
    campo.setCustomValidity(msg); 
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="rut" required oninput="checklargo(this, 10)" placeholder="Rut">
<input type="text" name="nombre" required oninput="checklargo(this, 5)" placeholder="Nombre">
```

Todo se podría hacer en una sola línea, aunque probablemente no sería tan legible. Al menos la declaración de la variable se puede hacer con asignación ternaria:

```
var msg = (palabra.length > max) ? 'Excede el largo permitido' : '';
```

**Actualización:** Modifiqué el nombre del primer parámetro que recibe la función, para evitar confusiones. Y agregué un segundo parámetro para especificar la longitud máxima del campo.

Ahora puedes usarlo para más de 1 validación.

Comment: Hola: 
Muchas gracias finalmente ocupé tu función y funciona de maravilla.lo que si tengo otra duda si quisera usar la misma función para validar otros campos, tendría que crear otras funciones y recibir el objeto del form? o la variable funciona como local y aunque se llame nombre serviría igual, funcionando como cualquier otra variable?
Saludos y gracias por responder.

Comment: Revisa la actualización. Si la respuesta te sirvió, no olvides marcarla como aceptada.

Comment: la validación ternaria no me resultó, aunque estoy probando la modificación que hiciste.
Aunque creo q estoy entendiendo porqué no resultó 
Saludos y muchas gracias

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar el atributo `maxlength` de `html` para restringir la cantidad de caracteres de tus `input`.

```html
<input type="text" name="rut" required maxlength="5" placeholder="Rut">
<input type="text" name="nombre" required maxlength="8"  placeholder="Nombre">
```